# Some datatype values lost after writing spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to spark.

I have a dataframe like below. This is a example dataframe and ID has 32 characters and I cast its type to integer.

```
ID,                             Transaction_amount,    Year
11111111111111111111111111111111,   1000,              2016
22222222222222222222222222222222,   2000,              2017
11111111111111111111111111111111,   1000,              2018
33333333333333333333333333333333,   3000,              2018
```

I wanted to partition the dataframe according to ID and write each partition to a csv file. So I write following code.

```
 df
  .write
  .partitionBy("ID")
  .csv("/path")
```

It gave me a output csv file like below (when ID = 11111111111111111111111111111111).

```
1000,2016
1000,2018
```

As you can see ID value is missing in the file.
So, I update my code as below.

```
     df
      .withColumn("ID_", $"ID")
      .write
      .partitionBy("ID_")
      .csv("/path")
```

It gave me following result.

```
,1000,2016
,1000,2018
```

As you can see ID value is missing.

My expected output csv file should be like as below (when ID = 11111111111111111111111111111111).

```
11111111111111111111111111111111,1000,2016
11111111111111111111111111111111,1000,2018
```

As a beginner I think its something with the datatype of ID. Because when I change the datatype of ID to String it gave a output like above but partitioning didn't work as the way I wanted. When I checked a csv file it was a collection of all IDs.

Can someone help with my code.
Thank you :)

Comment: Umh if you just want to partition your file by ID, you could use the partitionBy method: `df.write.partitionBy("ID")`

Comment: @AntonioCalì the problem is ID is not in the output csv file even after I create a duplicate ID column.

Comment: @AntonioCalì thank you for your solution. But, it gave me the same output (without ID)

Comment: I know it's a silly comment, but are you sure that for those rows, ID is 1 and not empty/null?

Comment: Yeah.. I'm sure about that :)

Comment: Why are you creating the `rank` column. This `df.withColumn("ID_", $"ID").write.partitionBy("ID_").csv("path")` seems to be working fine for me on Spark 2.3.2.

Comment: Rank has no purpose here...

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, but running on databricks.

Comment: Considering about most of the comments I edit my code. But it didn't give me the expected output either.

Comment: Sample output  `,1000,2016` As you can see ID value is null.

Comment: Umh, I think you should not cast to Integer such a big number because precision loss. Try to convert it to a [BigInt](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.5/scala/BigInt.html)